# TypeError: Cannot read property 'instances' of undefined

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, ts-jest

I am trying to use jest to mock an imported class inside a typescript class, the following code is used for the main program.

```
export class TasApiFeatureProvider extends FilteredFeatureProvider {
constructor(protected httpClient: AxiosHttpClient, clientSettings: IVariantAssignmentClientSettings) {
    super(clientSettings);
}

public async fetch() : Promise<IVariantAssignmentResponse>{
    //Set filters
    let headers: any = {};
    let filters = this.getFilters();

    // Filters are handled using Map<string,any> therefore we need to
    // convert these filters into something axios can take as headers.
    for (let key of filters.keys()) {
        const filterValue = filters.get(key);
        headers[key] = filterValue;
    }

    let response: AxiosResponse<ITasVariantAssignmentData> = await this.httpClient.get({ headers: headers });

    

    // received response from server
    let responseData = response.data;
    let configs = responseData.Configs;
    

    return {
        responseData;
    };
}
```

}

This is how my test class looks like

```
import { TasApiFeatureProvider } from "../providers/TasApiFeatureProvider"
import * as axiosHttpClient from "../utils/AxiosHttpClient"
describe('service', () => {

const mocked = axiosHttpClient as jest.Mocked<typeof axiosHttpClient>;
const AxiosHttpClient = mocked.AxiosHttpClient;

beforeEach(() => {
    AxiosHttpClient.mockClear();
});

it('The consumer should be able to call new() on AxiosHttpClient', async () => {
    //Arrange
    const settings = { getParameters: () => new Map<string, any>(), endpoint: '' };
    const mockedHttpClient = AxiosHttpClient.mock.instances[0];
    const tasAPIFeatureProvider = new TasApiFeatureProvider(mockedHttpClient, settings);

    //Act

    //Assert
    expect(tasAPIFeatureProvider).toBeTruthy();
});
```

});

However while running the test, getting an error while accessing the instance of mocked object

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'instances' of undefined

  28 |         //Arrange
  29 |         const settings = { getParameters: () => new Map<string, any>(), endpoint: '' };
> 30 |         const mockedHttpClient = AxiosHttpClient.mock.instances[0];
     |                                                       ^
  31 |         const tasAPIFeatureProvider = new TasApiFeatureProvider(mockedHttpClient, settings);
  32 |
  33 |         //Act
```

Any suggestions how I can inject the dependency + do the automatic mocking of an object here?

Comment: Where did you mock `axiosHttpClient`?

Comment: const mocked = axiosHttpClient as jest.Mocked<typeof axiosHttpClient>; @slideshowp2

Comment: Thanks @slideshowp2..forgot to mock..thanks for highliting it..jest.mock('../utils/AxiosHttpClient');

Comment: So the problem is solved?